# Dynamically Created Button Events in MFC Doesn't Fire After Clicking the Button

Tags: c++, mfc

So i was asked to make a bunch of buttons in MFC to update the app with new functions.

What have i done is

a. Reserving the ID in resource.h

```
#define IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_1               40501
#define IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_2               40502
#define IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_3               40503
#define IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_4               40504
#define IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_5               40505
```

I also have made sure that there's no duplicate ID in the resource.h

b. To create the button i have inserted these codes in the     CMainFrame::OnCreate() function

```
//Custom function start
cButtonA = new CButton();
cButtonB = new CButton();
cButtonC = new CButton();
cButtonD = new CButton();
cButtonE = new CButton();
cButtonA->Create(_T("My button 1"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(btnLeft1, btnTop1, btnRight1, btnBottom1), this, IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_1);
cButtonB->Create(_T("My button 2"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(btnLeft1, btnTop2, btnRight1, btnBottom2), this, IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_2);
cButtonC->Create(_T("My button 3"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(btnLeft1, btnTop3, btnRight1, btnBottom3), this, IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_3);
cButtonD->Create(_T("My button 4"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(btnLeft2, btnTop1, btnRight2, btnBottom1), this, IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_4);
cButtonE->Create(_T("My button 5"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(btnLeft2, btnTop2, btnRight2, btnBottom2), this, IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_5);
```

Header File:

```
CButton*                cButtonA; //First Button
CButton*                cButtonB; //Second Button
CButton*                cButtonC; //Third Button
CButton*                cButtonD; //Fourth Button
CButton*                cButtonE; //Fifth Button
```

c. For the message map i have tried both of these and neither of them works or catch the functions as for the ShowTestMessage function it only just contain a placeholder AfxMessageBox code. Tried putting breakpoints on those too and it still doesn't work.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CMDIFrameWnd)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMainFrame)
//Method 1
ON_COMMAND_RANGE(IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_1, IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_13, &CMainFrame::ShowTestMessage)

//Method 2
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_1, &CMainFrame::ShowTestMessage)
```

d. I also have made sure that the functions in MainFrm.h who handle the events has afx_msg prefix.

```
    protected:
    //{{AFX_MSG(CMainFrame
    afx_msg void ShowTestMessage();
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP(
```

Other things that i have tried intercepting the message by adding some line of codes in PreTranslateMessage

```
if (pMsg->message == BN_CLICKED){ //This doesn't work
    AfxMessageBox("Ohlala", MB_OK);
}

if (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN){ //This one work
    AfxMessageBox("Ohlala", MB_OK);
}
```

Then i tried changing the event handle to

```
void CMainFrame::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
```

Yet this one also doesn't fire (Since the breakpoint isn't triggered)

So did i miss something? I have to admit i'm not really good at MFC. I tried searching for all the probable mistake that i probably made yet i still can't find out why the event doesn't fire. @__@

EDIT1: If it helps i'm developing this in Visual Studio 2013 and this project (maybe) use MDI judging by the class declaration that i found in the header.

```
class CMainFrame : public CMDIFrameWnd
```

Comment: Do you see the buttons which you created? Explain what settings you used to create the project, for example MDI with Doc/View support + standard or office style...

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Yes i can see the buttons that i created, i'm not really sure as i am not the one who create the project file but AFAIK this doesn't use Ribbon Style.

Comment: I don't know what is going on. I think that should work. Maybe you are doing something odd in `PreTranslateMessage` or elsewhere. Or try different values for `IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_1` in case there is collision.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani btw i've tried looking at it and i think its a MDI since the MainFrm class contains `class CMainFrame : public CMDIFrameWnd` what kind of code that you expect ruining the event handling? Ok, i'll change the IDC_MAINFRM_BTN_1 tomorrow and see if the problem caused by the value collision. Thanks btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an odd way to place buttons, because the frame usually has children windows (like a child frame and the MDI frames and so on), but here it is, working with a SDI frame (I did not test it for a MDI frame, though):

In `CMainFrame`:

```
CButton*                testButton;

afx_msg void ShowTestMessage();
```

In `CMainFrame::OnCreate` at the end:

```
testButton = new CButton();
testButton->Create(_T("My button 1"), 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(10, 10, 100, 30), this, ID_TEST_BUTTON);
```

The 'click' method:

```
afx_msg void CMainFrame::ShowTestMessage()
{
    AfxMessageBox(L"Bingo!");
}
```

In message map:

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_TEST_BUTTON, &CMainFrame::ShowTestMessage)
```

Later Edit: If you really want the buttons in the client area, then you'll have some work to do. First, derive a 'child frame', something like that:

`class CChildFrame : public CMDIChildWndEx`

Second, replace the child frame from the document template with yours, something like that:

`m_pWhateverDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(
            IDR_SOME_ID,
            RUNTIME_CLASS(CWhateverDoc),
            RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame),
            RUNTIME_CLASS(CWhateverView));
AddDocTemplate(m_pWhateverDocTemplate);`

What's being changed here is the `CChildFrame` instead of the default `CMDIChildWndEx`. Now you can create your buttons in the client window. Maybe you can override the `OnCreateClient` and create them in there. You should be able to handle the buttons clicks in the client class.

Comment: OP says the buttons are showing, so that shouldn't be an issue. But you are right that it is an odd place for putting buttons.

Comment: @AdrianRoman Where is the correct place to put the buttons? Btw i just have learned that the project probably has MDI Frame judging by his snippet that i found in the MainFrm header `class CMainFrame : public CMDIFrameWnd`. I just literally learned MFC over the weekends and i'm still confused with it since its really different from developing java program @__@

And oh, it still doesn't work. I tried replacing the message map with the one that you wrote. :/ Maybe there's something messing with the message like @Barmak said :/

Comment: You have replicated the exact code the OP already had. That's not helpful. @EiZenHoweLL: You are trying to learn MFC, C++, and Windows programming all at the same time. Not going to work, ever. [Prerequisites for learning MFC programming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18165076/1889329) tells you, what's required. If you are impatient, have a look at [TN021: Command and Message Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt2c310k.aspx).

Comment: "You have replicated the exact code the OP already had" The difference is that it's actually working. I can see the message box when clicking the button. I don't know if it's 'exact replication' since for example I don't see a `new CButton()` in the OP code.

Comment: I don't know what is your purpose of placing the buttons in there, I would probably put them in a toolbar, but you know better what the goals are. If your really want to put them in the client area, well, I'll edit the answer and add a suggestion. You'll have some work to do...

Comment: Alright thanks! Your solution is working, i don't know that i have to put them inside another container. I'm assuming the MainFrame itself is already a container. I just have to solve how to call them correctly inside my MainFrame::OnCreate() i still have assertion error that probably caused by my barbaric codes.