# Visual Studio 2010 C++ MFC: Media Player

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am new to Programming with C++ although I have experience in Embedded C. "*Now I am given a task to make a customized media player which only plays '.avi', in Visual Studio 2010 C++ MFC. Where should I start?*" Edit: I was able to create a video player using a "Animation Control Tool". At this point I have hardcoded the path to the video. I want to implement Play, Pause, Stop for this video which is playing in the "Animation Control". Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prerequisites for learning MFC programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165076/prerequisites-for-learning-mfc-programming)

Comment: *"Where should I start?"* - Probably by taking the [tour]. This questions is wildly off-topic. But to put things into perspective: You will need to understand the Windows API, key concepts of C++ (**intimately!**), and COM (including event sinks). The latter is often hard to grasp, even for experienced developers. Consider informing your clients, that you won't be able to deliver.