# Visual Studio MFC C++ Problem with radio buttons with variables

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie learning to make a MFC App C++ in Visual Studio 2019.

I have 1 EDIT CONTROL, ID = txtResult, with a value CString variable `resultText`.

I have a group of 2 RADIO BUTTONS:

- ID: btnUp
- ID: btnLow

and I have 1 "Apply" BUTTON with ID = btnApply.

I tried adding a variable to the radio button itself (Right-Click, Add Variable, Category: Value, bool variable radioUp) but I get an error as soon as I run with that added in `dlgdata.cpp`.

> Debug Assertion Failed! File:
> d:\agent_work\3\s\src\vctools\VC7Libs\Ship\ATLMFC\Src\MFC\dlgdata.cpp
> Line: 269

The error is getting in the way; it doesn't seem to like me assigning a bool variable to the radio button itself.

Comment: [Prerequisites for learning MFC programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18165076/1889329).

Comment: Assure that radioUpperCase and other radio button member variable are valid, and call UpdateData() before use it.

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation for `DDX_Radio`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-exchange-routines?view=msvc-160#ddx_radio)?  It's not a boolean value per control, it's a single integer telling you *which* control is selected.

Answer (score -1):

Your radio buttons must belong to a group so that the auto behavior knows how to handle unchecking. Make sure that the resource file defines the first radio button in the group as "BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_GROUP" and not just "BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON"